# How to Iterate the JAVA Object LIST made from GSON

Tags: java, json, list, gson

I'm generating JAVA Objects from JSON String. But I'm getting problem in iterating the list item. This JSON is an nested array. Here is my java code

```
 response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    nString xr = request.getParameter("JSONString");
    Gson gson = new Gson(); 
    java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<List<EmployeeJSONObj>>(){}.getType();
    List<EmployeeJSONObj>l = gson.fromJson(xr, type);
    List<EmployeeJSONObj>l1 = l.get(0).getChild();

for(int i=0;i<l1.size();i++)
           {
               out.println("Name: "+l1.get(i).getName()+"<br/>");
           }
```

AND My java custom class is

```
public  class EmployeeJSONObj {
    private String name;
    private List<EmployeeJSONObj> children = new LinkedList<>();
    EmployeeJSONObj()
    {

    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public List<EmployeeJSONObj> getChild()
    {
        return children;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "name: " + name + ", children = " + children;
    }

}
```

AND JSON String is coming fro HTML hidden field and here is my json string

```
String str = "[{" + 
            "   \"name\": \"3214657890RootSAPSSE\"," + 
            "   \"children\": [{" + 
            "       \"name\": \"672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionCustomer Representative\"," + 
            "       \"children\": [{" + 
            "           \"name\": \"672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionPeão\"," + 
            "           \"children\": [{" + 
            "               \"name\": \"910MAZHAR .Sales Base Market SectionCustomer Representative\"," + 
            "               \"children\": [{" + 
            "                   \"name\": \"910MAZHAR .Sales Base Market SectionPeão\"," + 
            "                   \"children\": [{" + 
            "                       \"name\": \"713NOSHERWAN .Sales Sargodha SectionCustomer Representative\"," + 
            "                       \"children\": [{" + 
            "                           \"name\": \"713NOSHERWAN .Sales Sargodha SectionPeão\"" + 
            "                       }," + 
            "                       {" + 
            "                           \"name\": \"1161SAQLAIN .Sales Toba Taik Singh SecPeão\"" + 
            "                       }]" + 
            "                   }]" + 
            "               }]" + 
            "           }]" + 
            "       }," + 
            "       {" + 
            "           \"name\": \"1161SAQLAIN .Sales Toba Taik Singh SecCustomer Representative\"," + 
            "           \"children\": [{" + 
            "               \"name\": \"1179SHAMOON .Administration SectionDriver ( R )\"" + 
            "           }]" + 
            "       }]" + 
            "   }," + 
            "   {" + 
            "       \"name\": \"1179SHAMOON .Farooq Khan TrustDriver ( D)\"" + 
            "   }]" + 
            "}]";
```

When I run the above code it only show on level childrens. But I want to iterate whole list of objects.

Any idea? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use recursion to run over children of `EmployeeJSONObj`

```
public class Help {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str = "[{" + 
            "   \"name\": \"3214657890RootSAPSSE\"," + 
            "   \"children\": [{" + 
            "       \"name\": \"672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionCustomer Representative\"," + 
            "       \"children\": [{" + 
            "           \"name\": \"672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionPeão\"," + 
            "           \"children\": [{" + 
            "               \"name\": \"910MAZHAR .Sales Base Market SectionCustomer Representative\"," + 
            "               \"children\": [{" + 
            "                   \"name\": \"910MAZHAR .Sales Base Market SectionPeão\"," + 
            "                   \"children\": [{" + 
            "                       \"name\": \"713NOSHERWAN .Sales Sargodha SectionCustomer Representative\"," + 
            "                       \"children\": [{" + 
            "                           \"name\": \"713NOSHERWAN .Sales Sargodha SectionPeão\"" + 
            "                       }," + 
            "                       {" + 
            "                           \"name\": \"1161SAQLAIN .Sales Toba Taik Singh SecPeão\"" + 
            "                       }]" + 
            "                   }]" + 
            "               }]" + 
            "           }]" + 
            "       }," + 
            "       {" + 
            "           \"name\": \"1161SAQLAIN .Sales Toba Taik Singh SecCustomer Representative\"," + 
            "           \"children\": [{" + 
            "               \"name\": \"1179SHAMOON .Administration SectionDriver ( R )\"" + 
            "           }]" + 
            "       }]" + 
            "   }," + 
            "   {" + 
            "       \"name\": \"1179SHAMOON .Farooq Khan TrustDriver ( D)\"" + 
            "   }]" + 
            "}]";

    System.out.println(str);

    Gson gson = new Gson(); 
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Employees>>(){}.getType();
    List<Employees >l = gson.fromJson(str, type);
    System.out.println(l);

    iterateOverEmployee(l); 
}

private static void iterateOverEmployee(List<EmployeeJSONObj> l) {
    for(EmployeeJSONObj emp: l){

        if(emp.getChildren() != null){

            for(int i=0;i<emp.getChildren().size();i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Name: "+emp.getChildren().get(i).getName()+"<br/>");
            }

            iterateOverEmployee(emp.getChildren());
        }           
    }
}
```

**EmployeeJSONObj**

```
public static  class EmployeeJSONObj {
    private String name;
    private List<EmployeeJSONObj> children;


    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "name: " + name + ", children = " + children;
    }
    public List<EmployeeJSONObj> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
    public void setChildren(List<EmployeeJSONObj> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Name: 672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionCustomer Representative<br/>
Name: 1179SHAMOON .Farooq Khan TrustDriver ( D)<br/>
Name: 672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionPeão<br/>
Name: 1161SAQLAIN .Sales Toba Taik Singh SecCustomer Representative<br/>
Name: 910MAZHAR .Sales Base Market SectionCustomer Representative<br/>
Name: 910MAZHAR .Sales Base Market SectionPeão<br/>
Name: 713NOSHERWAN .Sales Sargodha SectionCustomer Representative<br/>
Name: 713NOSHERWAN .Sales Sargodha SectionPeão<br/>
Name: 1161SAQLAIN .Sales Toba Taik Singh SecPeão<br/>
Name: 1179SHAMOON .Administration SectionDriver ( R )<br/>
```

*As a side note*

Use Notepad++ or other tool to format your Json string. By this way you can avoid some errors

Comment: This is fine but when I change the json string like when I add more child and make it more nested then It is again showing me only 2 childerens. My json is generating dynamically, and can be upto as many child as many user wants.

Comment: can you post json with more children? from your code `Employees emp = l.get(0);` we use only 1st child, so ...

Comment: This is my JSON String I am getting from HTML Hidden field. [{"name":"3214657890RootSAPSSE","children":[{"name":"672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionCustomer Representative","children":[{"name":"672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionPeão","children":[{"name":"910MAZHAR .Sales Base Market SectionCustomer Representative","children":[{"name":"910MAZHAR .Sales Base Market SectionPeão","children":

Comment: [{"name":"713NOSHERWAN .Sales Sargodha SectionCustomer Representative","children":[{"name":"713NOSHERWAN .Sales Sargodha SectionPeão"},{"name":"1161SAQLAIN .Sales Toba Taik Singh SecPeão"}]}]}]}]},{"name":"1161SAQLAIN .Sales Toba Taik Singh SecCustomer Representative","children":[{"name":"1179SHAMOON .Administration SectionDriver ( R )"}]}]},{"name":"1179SHAMOON .Farooq Khan TrustDriver ( D)"}]}]

Comment: AND here is what I am getting from your output [name: 3214657890RootSAPSSE, children = [name: 672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionCustomer Representative, name: 1179SHAMOON .Farooq Khan TrustDriver ( D)]]

Comment: It is giving me error bec the list l is of employee type and the function iterateOverEmployee takes list of EmployeeJSONObj. ???

Comment: Thanks man - I modified your recursive program. Great thanks. You are a guru of java ;)